# can I use ul li instead of select dropdown and with jquery make it part of a form?

Tags: jquery

I went really long way trying to rewrite select to ul li and style it accordingly. But I'm getting really annoyed with the weight of code and minor annoyances on the way.

So I'm thinking to ditch the idea completely, and just use normal ul li menu and some kind of javascript to make it function like select (for form submission etc).

So is this possible? any example code you can give me?

My concerns is Cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Given that you're using jQuery why don't you use one of the existing plugins that does this?

Comment: The jQuery plugins page is dead :-(

Comment: Yes you can, here is a [good example](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Lovely idea. I just made one in the fiddle check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/2/).

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: fantastic! man this is awesome, so simple and elegant... and cross-browser compatibility will go as far as css that manages ul li :)

Comment: @starx Thank you so much. But how can I add an arrow?

Comment: @TheHung I know it's late, but for other people that want to add an arrow, just add the following to `li.init`: `background:url(icon.png) no-repeat center right; background-size: 10px` :)

Answer (score 1):

To completely do it as list and with javascript is not the best idea because everyone that has no javascript cannot use this functionality.

Here is a jQuery implementation that has the regular form select fallback (In fact it maps a existing select). You just need to change the first selector and style the list ... the script does the rest.

```
jQuery( '.woocommerce-ordering select' ).each( function() {


    var target = jQuery( this );

    var selected = target.find( 'option:selected' ).text();



    var map = jQuery( '<div class="selectmap"><span>' + selected + '</span><ul class="selectmap"></ul></div>' ).insertAfter( target );


    target.hide();


    target.find( 'option' ).each( function() {

        var c = jQuery( this );
        var u = map.find( 'ul' );

        console.log( u );

        console.log( c.text() );

        jQuery( '<li data-value="' + c.attr( 'value' ) + '">' + c.text() + '</li>' ).appendTo( u );

    } );


    map.find( 'li' ).click( function() {

        map.find( 'span' ).text( jQuery( this ).text() );
        target.val( jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-value' ) ).trigger( 'change' );

    } );


} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for select replacemenet is this. It generates the basic html and event binding and then you can just style it with css. Check it out. http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/H63MU/

```
var ulSelect = function($select) {

    // $select.hide(); <-- Uncomment in production
    var $opts = $select.find('option');

    return (function() {

        var items = '',
            html = '';

        $opts.each(function() {
            items += '<li><a href="#" class="item">'+ $(this).text() +'</a></li>';
        });

        html =
            '<ul class="menu">'+
                '<li class="sub">'+
                    '<a class="sel" href="#">'+ $opts.filter(':selected').text() +'</a>' +
                    '<ul>' + items + '</ul>'+
                '</li>'+
            '</ul>';

        $(html)
            .find('.sub a')
            .click(function(e) { // You can attach more events...
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.parents('.menu').find('.sel').text($this.text());
                $opts.eq($this.parent().index()).prop('selected', true);
            }).end().insertAfter($select);

    }());

};

ulSelect($('#select'));
```