# Creating a select drop-down list that expands when a user hover over an option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a select element which has a basic list, then when the user hovers over an option it expands to shows a more complete list.

I started by using css to hide all the values I wanted hidden, but this did not adjust the height of the select dropdown, so I was left with a lot of white space.

I then tried to have two selects, one with the reduced list, the other with the complete list(which is hidden). I then used javascript to copy the options from the complete list to the reduced list, when a user hover on the 'Other' optgroup. The code for this is shown below.

Html:

```
<select id="Title">
     <option value="">Select...</option>
     <option value="MR">Mr</option>
     <option value="MISS">Miss</option>
     <option value="MRS">Mrs</option>
     <optgroup label="Other">Other</optgroup>
</select>

<select id="FullTitle" style="display:none">
     <option value="">Select...</option>
     <option value="MR">Mr</option>
     <option value="MISS">Miss</option>
     <option value="MRS">Mrs</option>
     <option value="MS">Ms</option>
     <option value="DR">Doctor</option>         
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('select').find('optgroup').hover(
              function () { 
                var parent = $(this).parent()
                var selected = parent.find('option:selected').val()
                var id = "#Full" + parent.attr('id')                
                parent.html($(id).html())
                parent.find('option[value="'+ selected +'"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
              })
        </script>
```

This works fine in firefox but does not work in either IE or Chrome. I am not sure why.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this is not working or a better approach to my problem?

Comment: Aside from technical limitations, is this really something that a user will expect? Sometimes, simpler is better. And by sometimes, I mean usually.

Comment: I do agree with you. But for this project we have been asked for this by the user, as they want a list of about 20 different titles. Most of which will only be used once in a blue moon

Comment: You could simply sort the list of options with the most common at the top. Arrange the additional options in an `<optgroup>`.

Answer (score 1):

Hover events don't fire for options in IE and Chrome.  There are some scripts you can try that might do this, and I've seen other posts on this site about it as well:

[jquery hover event doesn't work with select option tag in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240205/jquery-hover-event-doesnt-work-with-select-option-tag-in-google-chrome)

From what I've seen, converting this into a div/ul and using css/jquery to make it look like a select list might by your best bet.

Comment: I think I will give this ago and add the code when I have completed it. Thank you

Comment: Good luck -- Here are a couple posts that can help get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716212/can-i-use-ul-li-instead-of-select-dropdown-and-with-jquery-make-it-part-of-a-for and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761273/jquery-how-to-cut-li-elements-from-one-ul-to-another-ul